# Запуск консольной программы в отдельном окне

Tags: python, windows, консоль

Kак запустить консольную программу через Python, но в отдельном окне?

Comment: в какой операционной системе для начала?

Comment: windows 8.1 а это имеет значение?

Comment: в консоли `start cmd /k python filename.py`

Comment: если уж ос не имеет значение, то что тогда имеет мм?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого вы можете использовать функцию `startfile` модуля `os`:
`os.startfile(путь_к_файлу)`